# Showing properties of a function and its inverse image

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, functions, discrete-mathematics

I tried proving the following question but did not get too far.

---

Let $\ f:A \to B$  be a function and $\ f^{-1}(Y)$ be the inverse image of $\ Y\subseteq B$ on $\ f$. Consider the following conditions:

1. $\ f$ is injective
2. $\ f$ is surjective
3. $\ f$ is bijective

Proof that one of these conditions is sufficient and necessary for showing that for all $\ X\subseteq A$ the following holds: $\ f^{-1}(f(X))=X$

---

It might be basic and I tried mostly by showing that injectivity is enough for proving it but I didnt really understand how to achieve the proof. I don't think it would help to post one of my long examples, I realised that it couldn't be a proof in the end so I gave up after this long try.

Comment: Are these discrete sets? $A$ and $B$ that is

Comment: I am not sure but I dont think, just regular sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general $$x\in f^{-1}(X)\iff f(x)\in X\tag1$$

Observe that $x\in X\implies f(x)\in f(X)\implies x\in f^{-1}(f(X))$ so it is *always* true that: $$X\subseteq f^{-1}(f(X))\tag2$$ *Essential* is the information $f^{-1}(f(X))\subseteq X$ for every $X\subseteq A$.

Applying this on $X=\{a\}$ where $a\in A$ we get $f^{-1}\left(f\left(\left\{ a\right\} \right)\right)\subseteq\left\{ a\right\} $
or equivalently $\left\{ x\in A\mid f\left(x\right)=f\left(a\right)\right\} =\left\{ a\right\} $.

This shows that $f$ sends only **one** element of $A$ to $f(a)$ and tells us that $f$ is injective.

---

Conversely let $f$ be an injective function. If $x\in f^{-1}(f(X))$ then $f(x)\in f(X)$ so $f(x)=f(y)$ for some $y\in X$. Then the injectivity of $f$ tells us that $x=y\in X$.

So $f^{-1}(f(X))\subseteq X$ as was to be shown.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the excellent explanation!

Comment: You are very welcome.